# Can I shorten and simplify my dplyr code with `across` or `{purrr}` syntax?

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

From the list `corresp` and `df_modifies` :

```r
# Note : corresp must be a list and not a data.frame 

corresp <- list(
  a_remplacer = c("abricot1"),
  remplacant = c("abricot2")
)

df_modifies <- data.frame(
  produit = c("abricot1", "abricot2"),
  m0123 = c(3, NA),
  m0223 = c(2.5, NA),
  m0323 = c(3, 2),
  m0423 = c(NA, 3)
)
```

I'd like to get the following result :

```r
   produit m0123 m0223 m0323 m0423
1 abricot2     3   2.5     2     3
```

My code is long and I'd like to shorten it maybe with `across` or `{purrr}`.

```r
library(dplyr)

modifies <- data.frame(
  produit = corresp$remplacant) |> 
  mutate(
    m0123 = ifelse(is.na(df_modifies$m0123[df_modifies$produit %in% corresp$remplacant]),
                   df_modifies$m0123[which(!is.na(df_modifies$m0123))[1]],
                   df_modifies$m0123[df_modifies$produit %in% corresp$remplacant]),
    m0223 = ifelse(is.na(df_modifies$m0223[df_modifies$produit %in% corresp$remplacant]),
                   df_modifies$m0223[which(!is.na(df_modifies$m0223))[1]],
                   df_modifies$m0223[df_modifies$produit %in% corresp$remplacant]),
    m0323 = ifelse(is.na(df_modifies$m0323[df_modifies$produit %in% corresp$remplacant]),
                   df_modifies$m0323[which(!is.na(df_modifies$m0323))[1]],
                   df_modifies$m0323[df_modifies$produit %in% corresp$remplacant]),
    m0423 = ifelse(is.na(df_modifies$m0423[df_modifies$produit %in% corresp$remplacant]),
                   df_modifies$m0423[which(!is.na(df_modifies$m0423))[1]],
                   df_modifies$m0423[df_modifies$produit %in% corresp$remplacant])
  )
```

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how a scaled version of this answer would work, but you can use `across` this way:

```r
df_modifies |> 
  summarise(across(-produit, \(x) ifelse(is.na(x[produit == corresp$remplacant]), 
                                         x[produit == corresp$a_remplacer],
                                         x[produit == corresp$remplacant])),
            produit = corresp$remplacant)

#   m0123 m0223 m0323 m0423  produit
# 1     3   2.5     2     3 abricot2
```

Answer (score 2):

Fill the NAs then subset:

```
# fill NAs
df_modifies_fill <- data.frame(lapply(df_modifies, zoo::na.locf))
#    produit m0123 m0223 m0323 m0423
# 1 abricot1     3   2.5     3     3
# 2 abricot2     3   2.5     2     3

# then subset based on correst list value
df_modifies_fill[df_modifies_fill$produit == corresp$a_remplacer, ]
#    produit m0123 m0223 m0323 m0423
# 1 abricot1     3   2.5     3     3

# or loop through all list values
lapply(corresp, function(i) df_modifies_fill[df_modifies_fill$produit == i, ])
# $a_remplacer
#    produit m0123 m0223 m0323 m0423
# 1 abricot1     3   2.5     3     3
# 
# $remplacant
#    produit m0123 m0223 m0323 m0423
# 2 abricot2     3   2.5     2     3
```

Answer (score 0):

The first two approaches use tidyverse and the third uses data.table .

**1) proc_transpose/coalesce** We transpose the `m...` columns of `df_modifies` using `proc_transpose` and use `coalesce` to perform the NA elimination.  Finally use `proc_transpose` again to convert back to the original form.

Note that `proc_transpose` conceptually

- moves the `id=` column to row names
- transposes that (which also interchanges row and column names)
- convert that matrix to a data frame
- moves the resulting row names back to a new `NAME` column

The code is

```
library(dplyr)
library(procs)

df_modifies %>%
  proc_transpose(id = produit) %>%
  reframe(NAME, 
    value = coalesce(.[[corresp$remplacant]], .[[corresp$a_remplacer]])) %>%
  proc_transpose(id = "NAME") %>%
  mutate(produit = corresp$remplacant, .before = 1, NAME = NULL)

##    produit m0123 m0223 m0323 m0423
## 1 abricot2     3   2.5     2     3
```

**1a) pivot_** A variation of this is to use `pivot_longer` followed by `pivot_wider` to implement the transpose and at the end use `pivot_wider` to transpose back as shown:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df_modifies %>%
  pivot_longer(-produit) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "produit") %>%
  reframe(name, value = coalesce(.[[corresp$remplacant]], .[[corresp$a_remplacer]])) %>%
  pivot_wider %>%
  mutate(produit = corresp$remplacant, .before = 1)

## # A tibble: 1 × 5
##   produit  m0123 m0223 m0323 m0423
##   <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
## 1 abricot2     3   2.5     2     3
```

**2) data.frame/fill** An alternative is to convert `corresp` to a data frame and then join it to `df_modifies` so that sorting on `name` puts the rows in the order that will work if `fill` is applied to the `m...` columns.  Then take the last row and remove the `name` column.

Note that in the example the rows of `df_modifies` are already in the correct order so if we knew that we could avoid using `corresp` and the associated sorting leaving the solution as just `df_modifies %>% fill(starts_with("m")) %>% slice_tail(n = 1)`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr) # list_transpose
library(tidyr) # fill  
library(tibble) # enframe

df_modifies %>%
  left_join(enframe(list_transpose(corresp)[[1]]), by = c(produit = "value")) %>%
  arrange(name) %>%
  select(-name) %>%
  fill(starts_with("m")) %>%
  slice_tail(n = 1)

##    produit m0123 m0223 m0323 m0423
## 1 abricot2     3   2.5     2     3
```

**3) transpose/fcoalesce** This is similar to (1) except it uses data.table with `transpose` instead of `pivot_*`

```
library(data.table)

dt <- as.data.table(df_modifies)

dt[, transpose(.SD, make.names = "produit", keep.names = "name")][,
  c("value") := fcoalesce(get(corresp$remplacant), get(corresp$a_remplacer))][,
  transpose(.SD[, c("name", "value")], make.names="name", keep.names="produit")][,
  produit := corresp$remplacant][]

##     produit m0123 m0223 m0323 m0423
## 1: abricot2     3   2.5     2     3
```

### Update

Have updated a number of times to simplify and add alternatives.